# Order query by count of one-to-many relationship per hour - SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, relationship

I'm working on a video game auction website for buying/selling in-game items.
I want to be able to query the Auctions table and sort them by the "hottest" auctions. This is based on the number of bids/hour placed on an auction.

Here's the auction model:

```
class Auctions(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, index=True)
    posted = db.Column(db.DateTime())
    end = db.Column(db.DateTime())
    ...

    bids = db.relationship('Bids', backref='auctions', lazy='dynamic', order_by='desc(Bids.amount)', cascade="all, delete-orphan")
```

Here's the Bids model:

```
class Bids(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, index=True)
    bidder_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'), index=True)
    auction_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('auctions.id'), index=True)
    amount = db.Column(db.Integer)
    posted = db.Column(db.DateTime())
```

I'm able to sort them by the amount of bids like this:

```
hot_stmt = db.session.query(models.Bids.auction_id, func.count('*').label('bid_count')).group_by(models.Bids.auction_id).subquery()
hot = db.session.query(models.Auctions, hot_stmt.c.bid_count).outerjoin(hot_stmt, (models.Auctions.id == hot_stmt.c.auction_id)).order_by(hot_stmt.c.bid_count.desc()).limit(5)
```

I can calculate and list bids/hour with this:

```
for auc, count in hot:
    time_delta = datetime.utcnow() - auc.posted
    auc_hours = time_delta.seconds / 60 / 60
    print(auc.id, count / auc_hours)
```

How could I sort the query by bids/hour so that the query returns the top 5 hottest auctions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One useful approach is to create a dictionary with auctions as keys and bids/hr as values:

```
d = {}
for auc, count in hot:
    time_delta = datetime.utcnow() - auc.posted
    auc_hours = time_delta.seconds / 60 / 60
    d[auc] = count / auc_hours
```

Make a list of the auctions:

```
aucs = [auc for auc, count in hot]
```

Sort the list `aucs` based on the values (use the reverse keyword to put the highest values at the beginning of the list, since the sort function goes lowest-to-highest by default):

```
aucs.sort(key=d.get, reverse=True)
```

Comment: Thank you for the response! I wasn't clear in my original post. I want to have the query return the top 5 hottest auctions, so the ordering needs to be done with SQLAlchemy so that I can simply limit the query to get the top 5. 

This would work if I just query the auctions table for all current auctions and then sort it this way, I'm just worried about performance.

Comment: I'm virtually certain the `list.sort` function is written in C and is quite fast.  It would be easy to try and see if the performance is acceptable.

Comment: I'm mainly concerned about the load on the database. I don't know much about the performance difference between the two. I would think returning 1000+ results and then sorting/trimming would be slower than returning 5 results in an already sorted query.

Comment: It's not exactly what I'm looking for, but it gets the job done. I've set this up as a background process that updates every 5 seconds. That way it's not being run on every page request.